# How to select the nth child (odd) - not direct child?

Tags: css

I have been trying to add nth-child selector so every odd element (div class="progress-bar") has a different bg color. However, I am only able to change the color of div class progress. Somehow I do not know how to reach the one I need.

```html
  <div class="col-sm">

<h2 class="progress_h2_one"> progress</h2>
          <div class="progress">

            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
          </div>
<h2 class="progress_h2"> progress</h2>
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
          </div>
<h2 class="progress_h2"> progress</h2>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
<h2 class="progress_h2"> progress</h2>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the desired effect with this configuration, you'd have to add the nth declarative to the 'progress' class.

Or you can wrap all the 'progress-bar' classes in the same parent div

```
<div class='progress'>
  <div class='progress-bar'/>
  <div class='progress-bar'/>
  <div class='progress-bar'/>
  <div class='progress-bar'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.progress .progress-bar: nth-child(odd) { background: green; }
Try this 
$(". progress-bar:nth-child(odd)").css("background","red");